# Serre-Tate 1964 Woods Hole notes

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry

I am not sure if this is the right venue to ask this. Apologies in advance.

I would like to clarify the following. When people give as reference:

J.-P. SERRE and J. TATE.-Mimeographed notes from the 1964 A.M.S. Summer Institute in Algebraic Geometry at Woods Hole;

which notes do they exactly refer to? I downloaded a 1964 Woods Hole notes from Milne's site: http://www.jmilne.org/math/Documents/ but didn't find notes which were co-authored by Serre and Tate. There is one written solely by Tate and another solely by Serre. Another part contains notes by the two of them together with Lubin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are probably referring to the sections "Serre discussed..." and "Tate discussed..." in the Seminar report by Lubin, Serre, Tate, which outline what has become known as Serre-Tate theory. But without knowing the context, I can only guess. It is quite likely the author didn't have access to the notes of conference, because only a very small number were produced, and they have become available on the internet only fairly recently.

Comment: Some works which cited the Serre-Tate notes (in the manner mentioned above) that I know of are: Katz' Serre-Tate Local Moduli, Katz-Mazur's Arithmetic Moduli of Elliptic Curves and Peter Norman's Lifting Abelian Varieties. It is very likely that these authors have had direct access to the notes. Anyway, I do agree with you. We can only guess. Maybe it really was the Lubin-Serre-Tate notes.

Comment: Well, in that case, they were just being lazy (or assumed that the reader didn't have access).

Comment: I think this answer is exactly right.